# How to insert my data from Node JS to BigQuery

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-bigquery, sql-insert

This is my code in a class named bqConnection. How would I insert my data from node JS which results the following below to a specific table in bigquery named "sla_table" in the field "expected_start_date" with the parsed data I provided. The name of the location of the table is np-inventory-planning-thd.IPP_SLA.sla_table. According to the "dag_id" I want to appropriately put this parsed data into its correct row. This table is already made I just need to put this new cron parsed data into the expected_start_date field.

log data after parsed:
EFS-Winning-Route-daily-batch
Fri Jul 08 2022 23:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)
ft-parm-trumping-daily
Fri Jul 08 2022 21:20:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)
ft-parm-trumping-weekly
Sun Jul 10 2022 14:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)
IP_MASTER
Sat Jul 09 2022 04:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)
IPP_CYCLE_PARMS
Sat Jul 09 2022 13:45:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)
ipp-daily-backups
Sat Jul 09 2022 02:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)
oclt-leadtime-daily
Fri Jul 08 2022 23:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)
ope-metrics
Sat Jul 09 2022 13:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)
parm-lite-daily
Fri Jul 08 2022 21:30:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)
parm-lite-data-migration
Sat Jul 09 2022 08:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)
parm-lite-sunday-push-instance
Sun Jul 10 2022 09:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)

```js
async function accessData(){
    const access = await main();
    const result = access.dag_runs.map(file => ({start_date: file.start_date, end_date: file.end_date, state: file.state, dag_run_id: file.dag_run_id, dag_id: file.dag_id}))
    console.log(result);
    /*await bqConnection()
        .dataset('IPP_SLA')
        .table('sla_table')
        .insert(result);*/
    console.log(`Inserted ${result.length} rows`)
}

(async function () {
    const runs = [
        {
            start_date: '2022-06-26T23:00:00.742495+00:00',
            end_date: '2022-06-27T14:10:23.108401+00:00',
            state: 'failed',
            dag_run_id: 'scheduled__2022-06-25T23:00:00+00:00',
            dag_id: 'EFS-Winning-Route-daily-batch'
        },
        {
            start_date: '2022-07-07T21:20:00.566888+00:00',
            end_date: '2022-07-07T23:20:55.250911+00:00',
            state: 'failed',
            dag_run_id: 'scheduled__2022-07-06T21:20:00+00:00',
            dag_id: 'ft-parm-trumping-daily'

        },
        {
            start_date: '2022-07-03T14:00:00.779718+00:00',
            end_date: '2022-07-03T14:00:41.250433+00:00',
            state: 'failed',
            dag_run_id: 'scheduled__2022-06-26T14:00:00+00:00',
            dag_id: 'ft-parm-trumping-weekly'
        },
        {
            start_date: '2022-07-08T04:00:01.038023+00:00',
            end_date: '2022-07-08T05:08:59.597408+00:00',
            state: 'failed',
            dag_run_id: 'scheduled__2022-07-07T04:00:00+00:00',
            dag_id: 'IP_MASTER'
        },
        {
            start_date: '2022-07-08T13:45:00.757997+00:00',
            end_date: '2022-07-08T14:02:48.050405+00:00',
            state: 'success',
            dag_run_id: 'scheduled__2022-07-07T13:45:00+00:00',
            dag_id: 'IPP_CYCLE_PARMS'
        },
        {
            start_date: '2022-07-08T02:00:00.821824+00:00',
            end_date: '2022-07-08T02:02:06.027268+00:00',
            state: 'success',
            dag_run_id: 'scheduled__2022-07-07T02:00:00+00:00',
            dag_id: 'ipp-daily-backups'
        },
        {
            start_date: '2022-07-07T23:00:01.313332+00:00',
            end_date: '2022-07-07T23:02:37.032427+00:00',
            state: 'failed',
            dag_run_id: 'scheduled__2022-07-06T23:00:00+00:00',
            dag_id: 'oclt-leadtime-daily'
        },
        {
            start_date: '2022-07-08T13:00:00.471935+00:00',
            end_date: '2022-07-08T13:00:49.819534+00:00',
            state: 'success',
            dag_run_id: 'scheduled__2022-07-07T13:00:00+00:00',
            dag_id: 'ope-metrics'
        },
        {
            start_date: '2022-07-07T21:30:00.682954+00:00',
            end_date: '2022-07-07T21:33:29.885878+00:00',
            state: 'failed',
            dag_run_id: 'scheduled__2022-07-06T21:30:00+00:00',
            dag_id: 'parm-lite-daily'
        },
        {
            start_date: '2022-07-08T08:00:01.756909+00:00',
            end_date: '2022-07-08T08:35:55.043131+00:00',
            state: 'failed',
            dag_run_id: 'scheduled__2022-07-07T08:00:00+00:00',
            dag_id: 'parm-lite-data-migration'
        },
        {
            start_date: '2022-07-03T09:00:00.825694+00:00',
            end_date: '2022-07-03T09:10:31.680879+00:00',
            state: 'failed',
            dag_run_id: 'scheduled__2022-06-26T09:00:00+00:00',
            dag_id: 'parm-lite-sunday-push-instance'
        }
    ];

async function determineCron(result){
    /*dagID = result?.[0]?.dag_id || 0*/
    dagID = result ? result.dag_id : 0
    console.log(dagID)
    job = await bqConnection().query(`SELECT * FROM \`np-inventory-planning-thd.IPP_SLA.expected_sla\` where dag_id = "${dagID}"`)
    cronTime = job[0][0].cron_time
    var interval = parser.parseExpression(cronTime);
    console.log(interval.next().toString());
}
    for (let run of runs) {
        var re = new RegExp('(Central Daylight Time)');
        await determineCron(run);
    }
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Google-cloud/bigquery, send data from node.js to bigQuery.
Read more here https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/bigquery/latest

```
function main(datasetId = 'my_dataset', tableId = 'my_table') {
  // [START bigquery_table_insert_rows]
  // Import the Google Cloud client library
  const {BigQuery} = require('@google-cloud/bigquery');
  const bigquery = new BigQuery();

  async function insertRowsAsStream() {
    // Inserts the JSON objects into my_dataset:my_table.

    /**
     * TODO(developer): Uncomment the following lines before running the sample.
     */
    // const datasetId = 'my_dataset';
    // const tableId = 'my_table';
    const rows = [
      {name: 'Tom', age: 30},
      {name: 'Jane', age: 32},
    ];

    // Insert data into a table
    await bigquery
      .dataset(datasetId)
      .table(tableId)
      .insert(rows);
    console.log(`Inserted ${rows.length} rows`);
  }
  // [END bigquery_table_insert_rows]
  insertRowsAsStream();
}
main(...process.argv.slice(2));
```